# ACF - Unable to Save/Publish Option Page

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I hope all are well for all of you. I had previously posted my question on 
http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/unable-to-savepublish/ but not getting any replies, so I would like to try my luck here.

I am having some issues with saving Options, as well as publishing a New Page. I am doing it locally.

For Publishing a New Page, I am not able to update or publish a new page to my site without clicking review first.

As for Options Page, I am also having the same issue but I am unable to “cheat” by clicking ‘Preview’ as there isn’t an option to.

I would be glad and appreciate to receive any help given or suggested.

Comment: What happen when you try to update/publish? Any errors? Have you check if there is any in console?

Comment: @Piotr Hi. The loading icon will keeps loading, pages wouldnt refresh. I am not ruling out that the version of my WP and ACF are not compatible; need to update my ACF soon. I will update again after I have updated my ACF.

Comment: looks like javascript error. You should check console for more details. And there was an issue looks like your description with WP and ACF on some versions lately so updating could help.

Comment: @Piotr updated to ACF PRO 5, everything works as it should now.

Comment: Not too sure why my answer wasn't on this page (sent in my answer twice) but this is an short update for anybody encountered such problem like i did. :)